# Custom jQuery sorting on HTML navigation. How to order elements based on title?

Tags: jquery, sorting, navigation

I have a custom navigation built that I would like to apply a specific sort order based on their title. How would I go about sorting this menu so that instead of:

Site 1, Site 2, Site 3, Site 4

We get Site 3, Site 2, Site 4, Site 1

```
    <div class='navGroup' >
    <ul class='navSites'>
      <li>
        <a>Site 1</a><span class='exSpand'>[+]</span>
          <ul class='navSecondLevelSite'>
              <li><a href='/Home.aspx' >Home</a></li>
              <li><a href='/feedback.aspx' >Feedback</a></li>
              <li><a href='/OfficesMaps.aspx' >Offices Maps & Meeting Rooms</a></li>
              <li><a href='/SystemAlerts.aspx' >System Alerts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Site 2</a><span class='exSpand'>[+]</span>
          <ul class='navSecondLevelSite'>
              <li><a href='/Page1.aspx' >Page1</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page2.aspx' >Page2</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page3.aspx' >Page3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Site 3</a><span class='exSpand'>[+]</span>
          <ul class='navSecondLevelSite'>
              <li><a href='/Page1.aspx' >Page1</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page2.aspx' >Page2</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page3.aspx' >Page3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Site 4</a><span class='exSpand'>[+]</span>
          <ul class='navSecondLevelSite'>
              <li><a href='/Page1.aspx' >Page1</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page2.aspx' >Page2</a></li>
              <li><a href='/Page3.aspx' >Page3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Colbs/UyDLL/

Comment: Why do it client side? You're using asp.net, why not do it server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that requires an array based on the text. It removes all the elements and appends them in order defined by array

```
var navOrder=['Site 3','Site 2','Site 4','Site 1'];
var $nav=$('.navSites');
/* detach the list items */
var $items=$nav.children().detach();
/* loop over navOrder array */
$.each(navOrder, function(_, txt){
    $items.filter(function(){
        return $(this).children('a').text() == txt;
    }).appendTo($nav);/* append list item that matches array element value*/
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UyDLL/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! jQuery is so beautiful